# Automate the Boring Stuff with Python - Ch4 - Character Picture Grid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following along in this [book](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter4/), and although the below code runs, and produces the two hearts, I also end up with a 'None' at the end and I can't figure out why.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]


def heart(list):
    for i in range(len(grid[0])):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[j][i],end=' ')
        print('')

    for i in range(len(grid[0])-1,-1,-1):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[j][i],end=' ')
        print('')

print(heart(grid))
```

I've added an image of the result here:

[image: Successful hearts with ending None]

Comment: `heart()` doesn't return anything, it does its own printing. You don't need to call `print()` when you call it.

Comment: @G.Anderson I don't think that has the answer.

Comment: @Barmar - That cleared it up, thank you! Did not realize I was trying to double-print.